# How to find the general and particular solution of linear differential equation $xdy + (x^2 - y)dx = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the linear differential equation general and particular solution:
>   $$xdy + (x^2 - y)dx = 0$$
>   with $y(2) = 2$.

I am having difficulty solving the general equation. I tried to bring in the $μ$, but wasn't sure how to continue. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

$xdy + (x^2 - y)dx = xdy-ydx+x^2dx=0$ or $dx=-d\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$

Comment: $xdy+(x^2−y)dx=xdy−ydx+x^2dx=0$

Answer (score 0):

You have:

$xdy + (x^2 - y)dx = 0\\\implies x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+x^2-y=0\\\implies xy'-y=-x^2$

Now I agree that usually here comes $\mu(x)=e^{\alpha(x)}$ into play, but in this case you have $\mu(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$

Look: $xy'-y\implies \frac{x}{x^2}y'-\frac{1}{x^2}y=\frac1xy'+\left(\frac1x\right)'y=\left(\frac1xy\right)'$

So you get $$\left(\frac1xy\right)'=-x^2\frac1{x^2}=-1\\\implies \frac1xy=-x+c\\\implies y=-x^2+cx$$

Now you only left with putting $y(2)$ into there and finding $c$